# Problem with the protocol. MinecraftPing class

Tags: java, plugins, protocols, minecraft

I am using this method but I get an error necessary for the version (PaperSpigot 1.15.2):

```
public MinecraftPingReply getPing(final MinecraftPingOptions options) throws IOException {
        MinecraftPingUtil.validate(options.getHostname(), "Hostname cannot be null.");
        MinecraftPingUtil.validate(options.getPort(), "Port cannot be null.");

        final Socket socket = new Socket();
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(options.getHostname(), options.getPort()), options.getTimeout());

        final DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        final DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        //> Handshake

        ByteArrayOutputStream handshake_bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream handshake = new DataOutputStream(handshake_bytes);

        handshake.writeByte(MinecraftPingUtil.PACKET_HANDSHAKE);
        MinecraftPingUtil.writeVarInt(handshake, MinecraftPingUtil.PROTOCOL_VERSION);
        MinecraftPingUtil.writeVarInt(handshake, options.getHostname().length());
        handshake.writeBytes(options.getHostname());
        handshake.writeShort(options.getPort());
        MinecraftPingUtil.writeVarInt(handshake, MinecraftPingUtil.STATUS_HANDSHAKE);

        MinecraftPingUtil.writeVarInt(out, handshake_bytes.size());
        out.write(handshake_bytes.toByteArray());

        //> Status request

        out.writeByte(0x01); // Size of packet
        out.writeByte(MinecraftPingUtil.PACKET_STATUSREQUEST);

        //< Status response

        MinecraftPingUtil.readVarInt(in); // Size
        int id = MinecraftPingUtil.readVarInt(in);

        MinecraftPingUtil.io(id == -1, "Server prematurely ended stream.");
        MinecraftPingUtil.io(id != MinecraftPingUtil.PACKET_STATUSREQUEST, "Server returned invalid packet.");

        int length = MinecraftPingUtil.readVarInt(in);
        MinecraftPingUtil.io(length == -1, "Server prematurely ended stream.");
        MinecraftPingUtil.io(length == 0, "Server returned unexpected value.");

        byte[] data = new byte[length];
        in.readFully(data);
        String json = new String(data, options.getCharset());

        //> Ping

        out.writeByte(0x09); // Size of packet
        out.writeByte(MinecraftPingUtil.PACKET_PING);
        out.writeLong(System.currentTimeMillis());

        //< Ping

        MinecraftPingUtil.readVarInt(in); // Size
        id = MinecraftPingUtil.readVarInt(in);
        MinecraftPingUtil.io(id == -1, "Server prematurely ended stream.");
        MinecraftPingUtil.io(id != MinecraftPingUtil.PACKET_PING, "Server returned invalid packet.");

        // Close

        handshake.close();
        handshake_bytes.close();
        out.close();
        in.close();
        socket.close();

        return new Gson().fromJson(json, MinecraftPingReply.class);
    }




public class MinecraftPingUtil {

    public static byte PACKET_HANDSHAKE = 0x00, PACKET_STATUSREQUEST = 0x00,
            PACKET_PING = 0x01;
    public static int PROTOCOL_VERSION = 4;
    public static int STATUS_HANDSHAKE = 1;

    public static void validate(final Object o, final String m) {
        if (o == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException(m);
        }
    }

    public static void io(final boolean b, final String m) throws IOException {
        if (b) {
            throw new IOException(m);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @author thinkofdeath
     * See: https://gist.github.com/thinkofdeath/e975ddee04e9c87faf22
     */
    public static int readVarInt(DataInputStream in) throws IOException {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        while (true) {
            int k = in.readByte();

            i |= (k & 0x7F) << j++ * 7;

            if (j > 5)
                throw new RuntimeException("VarInt too big");

            if ((k & 0x80) != 128)
                break;
        }

        return i;
    }

    /**
     * @author thinkofdeath
     * See: https://gist.github.com/thinkofdeath/e975ddee04e9c87faf22
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void writeVarInt(DataOutputStream out, int paramInt) throws IOException {
        while (true) {
            if ((paramInt & 0xFFFFFF80) == 0) {
                out.writeByte(paramInt);
                return;
            }

            out.writeByte(paramInt & 0x7F | 0x80);
            paramInt >>>= 7;
        }
    }

}
```

More info: https://github.com/oliverdunk/MinecraftServerPing/tree/master/src/ch/jamiete/mcping

(for a Minecraft plugin) This version works with 1.8 and not in the version I need: 1.15.2
How can I solve it?

Error:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 17 path $.description
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextString(JsonReader.java:825) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-318]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$16.read(TypeAdapters.java:418) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-318]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$16.read(TypeAdapters.java:406) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-318]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-318]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-318]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-318]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-318]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-318]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:773) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-318]
    at it.justdevs.bw.lobby.utils.ping.MinecraftPing.getPing(MinecraftPing.java:121) ~[?:?]
    at it.justdevs.bw.lobby.utils.StatusItemStack.getItemStack(StatusItemStack.java:51) ~[?:?]
    at it.justdevs.bw.lobby.guis.Inventory.init(Inventory.java:38) ~[?:?]
    at it.justdevs.gui.utils.SmartInventory.open(SmartInventory.java:54) ~[?:?]
    at it.justdevs.gui.utils.SmartInventory.open(SmartInventory.java:37) ~[?:?]
    at it.justdevs.bw.lobby.commands.MainCommand.onCommand(MainCommand.java:26) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:45) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-318]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'd recommend you post your code in the question itself, rather than a link to the code. In addition, you need to specify the exact error message you're seeing in the question body (stack trace, error message, etc.), as it's unclear what problem you're actually having.

Comment: Thanks, keep giving me advice they are always useful, being the first time I publish something

Comment: The data that you got from the server isn't valid JSON. Do some debugging and see what it is.

Comment: What server software are you using? Vanilla? Bukkit? Spigot? Sponge? Please add the appropriate tag to your post.

Comment: In general always use Development Kit (forge/spigot/whatever) appropriate to your version of minecraft you want it to run on.
I suspect you try to run a mod compiled with 1.12 SDK on 1.15. This needs updating

Comment: Trying to fine tune the JSON I found the difference between the JSON versions:

{"description":{"text":"A Minecraft Server"},"players":{"max":8,"online":0},"version":{"name":"Spigot 1.15.2","protocol":578}}
        
{"description":"A Minecraft Server","players":{"max":8,"online":0},"version":{"name":"Spigot 1.8.8","protocol":47}}